# sample() not sampling randomly?

Tags: r

Can someone explain whats going wrong here?  I wanted to simulate 10,000 20-sided dice rolls.  I used this code:

`x <- sample(1:20,10000,replace=T)`

but that give me this:

```
hist(x)
```

[image: Plot 1]

It seems to be a problem above 12:
[image: Plot 2]
[image: Plot 3]

What am I not understanding here?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not actually to do with your `sample`, it's `hist`.

If you do this

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:20,10000,replace=T)
table(x)

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
513 522 482 495 459 549 506 505 518 498 495 492 440 490 459 509 496 528 511 533
```

you'll notice it's random.   However `hist` reproduces your graph.  If you count the bars you'll notice there are 19 and not 20.

Trying this instead:

```
bins <- seq(0, 20, by=1)
hist(x, breaks=bins)
```

gives a graph with even bar heights because all 20 bars are shown (i.e. 1 and 2 are not collapsed together).

[image]

Comment: Or just use `barplot(table(x))`